# SNMP service on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: snmp, windows-10-iot-core

does anybody know if a SNMP service exists for Windows 10 IoT Core (running on RaspberryPi3, preferred a C# source), so that I can query the Device like a PC/Server?

Comment: Have you checked the [Project Rome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices)?

Comment: As #SNMP Library is .NET Standard 1.3 compliant, you should be able to use it on Windows 10 IoT Core via UWP. However its agent sample is just a sample, https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/samples/agent-development.html no quality insurance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would say that WMI is the technology you should use if you want SNMP-like functionality from Windows, but WMI doesn't exist on Windows 10 IoT Core.

SNMP also doesn't exist on Windows 10 IoT Core.

There are open source SNMP servers and clients written in C#, and I don't know how easy these will be to port to UWP.  Might be easy, might not be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes on windows 10 SNMP agent exits.

By default that service is not installed, we need to install manually SNMP service on windows 10.

Please visit settings of your computer to install SNMP service on windows 10

Source:
http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/snmp-protocol/how-to-install-snmp-service-in-windows-10/